# How to ensure several Python processes access the data base one by one?

Tags: python, database, queue

I got a lot scripts running: scrappers, checkers, cleaners, etc. They have some things in common:

- they are forever running;
- they have no time constrain to finish their job;
- they all access the same MYSQL DB, writting and reading.

Accumulating them, it's starting to slow down the website, which runs on the same system, but depends on these scripts.

I can use queues with Kombu to inline all writtings.

But do you know a way to make the same with reading ?

E.G: if one script need to read from the DB, his request is sent to a blocking queue, et it resumes when it got the answer ? This way everybody is making request to one process, and the process is the only one talking to the DB, making one request at the time.

I have no idea how to do this.

Of course, in the end I may have to add more servers to the mix, but before that, is there something I can do at the software level ?

Comment: What database do you use? MySQL? SQLite?

Comment: Then you most likely don't have to do anything, your server software should handle this.

Comment: It doesn't. It's dying under the numerous requests, which are not terribly complicated, but numerous.

Comment: What is the size of the database? What is the size of the active dataset? Is it IO or CPU bound? Did you consider a Master-Slave setup? Do you use one already? You could load off all the reads to the slave node(s).

From my point of view you give way to little information to give the "right" answer to this question. But I'd still guess that queuing database reads won't solve your performance issues.

Comment: @till: My data base is not even bigger than 1 Go large. The problem is the CPU consumption. The active data set size varies from a script to another, I didn't measure them. I don't use slaves. I'm not going to if I can find a solution that avoid adding more servers. There is no really 'right answer'. I'm not looking for a silver bullet. I'll do tests and tests and tests. I just want to know If there is a way to inline reading. If there is, I'll try it. It it works, good, if it doesn't, I'll try something else.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a connection pooler and make the connections from the scripts go through it. It would limit the number of real connections hitting your DB while being transparent to your scripts (their connections would be held in a "wait" state until a real connections is freed).

I don't know what DB you use, but for Postgres I'm using PGBouncer for similiar reasons, see http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgbouncer/

Comment: Then perhaps this will work for you? http://www.quora.com/Is-there-something-similar-to-pgbouncer-for-MySQL

Comment: MySQL proxy is a bug nest, but sqlrelay may be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

You say that your dataset is <1GB, the problem is CPU bound.

Now start analyzing what is eating CPU cycles:

- Which queries are really slow and executed often. MySQL can log those queries.
- What about the slow queries? Can they be accelerated by using an index?
- Are there unused indices? Drop them!
- Nothing helps? Can you solve it by denormalizing/precomputing stuff?

Comment: No queries are slow. These are simple queries. All very simple, all very numerous. I do have some JOIN here and there, but there are not terrible. No heavy filtering on non indexed fields. No join on non indexed fields. I already analized what's eating the CPU. It's nothing in particular, it's the cumulating of all of it.

Comment: What volume of queries are are we talking about? What are the specifications of the database server? Does it do anything else than run the database?

Comment: The server runs a Django website with heavy disk and redis caching, serving using nginx. The Website itself is eating some 140 req/s. For the scripts, I don't know yet. There are not running all at the same time, all the time. I'm well aware of the limitation of this setup. Again, I'm not asking for miracles, I'm just asking for suggestions.

Comment: Any script individually runs fine. It's when most of them play together, read and write, that it get hards for the CPU to keep up with the DB sucking it up dry. I'm ok if the scripts are slow. There are essential, but have no time constraint.

Comment: Is that 140 cache misses per second or 140 requests per second, most of them go to the cache?

Comment: 140 requests that had to hit the DB and not the cache.

Comment: As others suggested already - connection pooling could help. It could also be indeed the time to separate the database server from the rest. Did you read [unbreaking django](http://thebuild.com/presentations/unbreaking-django.pdf)?

Comment: I did read it. There is nothing in it I already don't know. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that each process must call in order to talk to the DB. You could re-write the scripts so that they must call that function rather than talk directly to the DB. Within that function, you could have a scope-based lock so that only one process would be talking to the DB at a time.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would implement that. How would you make the lock ? How whould you check it in a consistent maner ? And above all, it's certainly not a problem that is new, so writting my own solution would probably reinventing the wheel, wouldn't it ?

Comment: Consider the DB your data structure, the processes your threads and your function the gateway to that data structure. Basic threading uses the same concepts. To make the structure thread safe, you have to lock it while each process/thread does its thing. This will ensure that only one process is reading at a time (per the original question).

Comment: These are several processes, not several threads. You can not make them several threads.